# Project path contains special characters which can cause Phonegap build failures

Tags: java, android, cordova, myeclipse

I installed myEclipse yesterday
and I am trying to create a new phonegap application project, but when I type the name,I constantly get an error on the top which says:

> Project path contains special characters which can cause Phonegap
>   build failures

[image: escreenshot of the errore]

I have also tried to repair my download by re-installing the whole myeclipse again but eventually it didn't work for me and i cannot write the Phonegap project name until now, so please offer help
thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in [this MyEclipse forum entry](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/project-path-contains-special-characters-which-can-cause-phonegap-build-failures/). As noted in the error message, the project path contains special characters. The project path consists of the workspace location for the project as well as the project name. The image shows that the default workspace location is to be used and that location has an apostrophe in the path (at "Joe's"). So you either need to deselect the "Use default location" option and enter a new location for the project, which doesn't have special characters in the path, or re-start MyEclipse with a workspace which is located on a path that doesn't contain special characters.